# Where can I ask about something I don't know anything about?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, asking-questions

Maybe this is too general a question, but I really get confused when I have a question and don't know in what site of "The Stack Exchange Network" I should ask this question.

I'm now searching for a site in the network to know more about "How to find how far an object is by a 3D image using two cameras".

I searched a lot to find a start or a small piece of information but Google didn't serve me.

If I want to ask my question in [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), my question will receive too many downvotes because I'm not providing any code or information.

And if I asked my question in [Super User](https://superuser.com/) I'll also get downvotes because my question is not related to any program.

And for other sites in the network my question will be too general and would be closed.

Is there a Stack Exchange website that allows to ask general programming questions that provides some general advice on how to start with things, for example with my previous question? If not, how can I find some answers for them on the network in an **"alternative way"**?

Comment: I'm making a random guess... but don't they do a lot of this sort of thing in mathematics or physics? Figuring out the height of mountains on Pluto based on their shadows....

Comment: SO Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241607/distance-to-the-object-using-stereo-camera

Comment: I don't know the right site for your question, but you don't need a "general usage" SE site -- if you have a specific question (like the one you mention here), you can ask a question with the tag [tag:site-recommendation] and people will recommend an SE site that will take your question (if there is one). Good luck!